# Rails - Order by self referential includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Run into an issue I've not come across before, and can't seem to find a solution online anywhere which is frustrating. Basically I have a users table which contains an `invited_by_id` column, referencing the same users table.

I'm now trying to create a query where it sorts the results based on the inviting users name, however using the usual active record sorting here doesn't really work

```
User
.includes(:invited_by)
.order("users.name ASC")
```

Because both of the tables in question are the same one, it seems rails is picking the first one, and not the invited_by association.

Is there any way of specifying that I want to order on the association?

**Further info**

I am trying to use this in an active record mixin, so I won't be calling this directly on the base class, and it needs to work with an existing scope as the mixing method will be called on the scope. For example

```
User
.includes(:invited_by)
.where(where_clause)
.sort(:invited_by_name, :asc)
```

Here, the `sort` method is provided by the mixin, and this is where it needs to be able to differentiate between the tables. I have logic that means it knows what the relation is, so it knows that `:invited_by_name` is the name column, of the :invited_by relationship, but that's as far as I've got.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the same table as different names. You can do this with Arel

```
guest = Arel::Table.new(:users, :as => 'guest')
inviter = Arel::Table.new(:users, :as => 'inviter')

relation = guest.
  project(Arel.sql('*')).
  join(inviter).on(guest[:invited_by_id].eq(inviter[:id])).
  order(inviter[:name])

@users = relation.to_sql
```

Comment: Would this work with an existing scope? The place where this will be is inside a mixin that is chained so needs to work with an existing scope rather than just the user model directly

Comment: Huh, no, I can't see it working or even imagine how to try it. I've just googled Arel with scopes and haven't seen anything usable.  There's this blog entry about changed Arel nodes but I'm not sure how helpful that would be to you... https://www.viget.com/articles/composable-sql-queries-in-rails-using-arel

Comment: hmm no that's my issue :( will keep digging